# Extent Report Image is not displayed

Tags: java, extentreports

I am using Extent Report for my selenium Test.

Capture screenshot:

```
public String captureScreen() throws IOException {
        TakesScreenshot screen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File src = screen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String dest = "./reports/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
        File target = new File(dest);
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, target);
        return target.getAbsolutePath();    
    }

    public ExtentTest startTestCase(String testName) {
        test = extent.createTest(testName);
        return test;
    }
public void endTestcase() {
        extent.setAnalysisStrategy(AnalysisStrategy.CLASS);
    }

    public void endResult() {
        extent.flush();
    }
```

To attach screenshot I am using below code:

```
test.pass("Navigated to  Payment Step 1 Page",MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreen()).build());
```

But the report looks good in local.. But I wanted to send the extent report in email.. The images are not displayed.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to store and link images from a shared or http location in order for them to be viewable. Or, send a zip file with all images attached.  Not sure how good the report will be viewed over email as there is a specific template for email.

Comment: You can link directly via a cloud provider (AWS, Dropbox etc) as long as the images are uploaded there while you run tests. Working with shared locations/drives however is what most people do, and it's probably more straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Step1 :  You have to create a new method getBase64Screenshot() and convert image into Base64 and call this method where ever you required 
"ActionsClass.java"

public static String getBase64Screenshot() throws IOException {

```
    Date oDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat oSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    String sDate = oSDF.format(oDate);
    String encodedBase64 = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    TakesScreenshot screenshot = (TakesScreenshot) Base.driver;
    File source = screenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String destination =System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Foldername\\target\\cucumber-reports\\"+"Screenshot_" + sDate + ".png";
    File finalDestination = new File(destination);
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);

    try {
        fileInputStream =new FileInputStream(finalDestination);
        byte[] bytes =new byte[(int)finalDestination.length()];
        fileInputStream.read(bytes);
        encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "data:image/png;base64,"+encodedBase64;
}
```

Step2 : To attach screenshot (Pass/Fail) in extent report we can use
Report.addScreenCaptureFromPath(ActionsClass.getBase64Screenshot());